# Using preg_replace() to replace content with a comma and space

Tags: preg-replace, str-replace

Trying to do preg_replace() but add a space after the comma i am replacing the line breaks with.

Currently this:

```
$string = preg_replace( "/\r/", ", ", $string );
```

But the space doesnt work.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `str_replace()`?

```
$test = "Hello\rWorld";

$test = str_replace("\r", ", ", $test);

print $test;
// Hello, World
```

[PHP Documentation for `str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)